# Google cloud storage object change notification retries even after responding with status 404

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In appengine logs I see the same OCN request being retried all day long and it replies a 404 each time. That specific endpoint has 74.96% error rate on 404s.

The doc explains the behaviors for 500, 502, 503, 502 ( retry ) and 102, 200, 201, 202, 204 ( success ).

And then says :

> Any other HTTP response codes returned by your application are treated as permanent failures and are not retried.

[link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Reliable_Delivery)